# giving a CSS class as part of a PHP if else statement

Tags: php, css

Is there a good way of calling a css class as part of a PHP if else statement? What I am trying to do is change the background color of a div that is a part of the html depending on the value of the results from a php if else statement.

**php**

```
 if(!empty($check_availability)){
     echo <div id="1"> do something <div> 
    // make the div background green if this is true
    }
    else {
    <div id="2"> do something else instead<div>
    //make backgound red if this is true
    }
```

**html**

```
<div id="container"> <!-- <<<<<<< this is the div that I want to change the background color of depending on results from the php -->
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are talking about conditionally adding classes to divs. `good` is subjective, but this is what I normally do.

```
$class = !empty($check_availability) ? 'green-class' : 'red-class';
echo "<div class='{$class}'> do something <div>";
```

Comment: Thanks so much I realized that my question was not as well formed as I wanted. I should clarify that I want to actually change the background color of an entirely different div not represented in the php based on the results of the php if that makes sense? I am amending above